# Custom CSS on element subject to state of child element in a preceding sibling element

Tags: css

I need to style a span element but only when a child element in a preceding sibling div element is active (i.e. a radio button has been checked).

I cannot amend the code. Can only use CSS.

Any thoughts?

```
<label class="One">
    <span class="Two">
        <div class="Three">
            <input class="Four" type="radio">
            <a class="Five ui-state-default"></a>
        </div>
        <span class="Six">Don't highlight this</span>
    </span>
</label>
<label class="One">
    <span class="Two">
        <div class="Three">
            <input class="Four" type="radio">
            <a class="Five ui-state-active"></a>
        </div>
        <span class="Six">Highlight this</span>
    </span>
</label>
```

- need to highlight span.Six but only when a.Five has "ui-state-active" shown.

An alternative, if easier, is I could instead highlight the label element (i.e. the second "label.One" above) but again *only* if the child element 3 levels down is "active".......

Appreciate the help

Comment: Can you move the anchor out of the div and parallel to the span you want to highlight?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately I can't. Its a radio button in a complex Wordpress forms plugin, and eventually I will have many hundreds of entries with this. I need to hide the button itself, and recreate a new button by highlighting the radio button's label....

Answer (score 0):

Given the conditions that you cannot amend the code and you have to use CSS only, the expected result is not possible. You can either use Javascript or modify the HTML. 
But, you can take the help of pseudo elements to nearly achieve what you want. The content of pseudo-elements can be changed based on the CSS rules.

```
input:checked~a:after {
  content: "I am active";
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

Here is the demo of what I am suggesting:
http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/3626/

You can style the pseudo elements in any manner you want.

In case of javascript ,you can start from here:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").on("change", function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.parents("label:first").find(".Six").toggleClass("active")
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/3628/

Comment: Thanks. I tried using various pseudo-elements to achieve this, but nothing had worked. The example of what you have in your demo is almost the same as the radio button showing now, which I need to hide instead. It is awkward because the anchor is inside the div, where the div is on the same level as the span element. As I cant change the HTML, could you suggest how this could be done using custom javascript?? - I dont know where to begin with that.....

Comment: I could actually style the parent span as an alternative too, if this is at all possible instead?  i.e.(per above)  style the `span.Two` when the `a.Five` is "active" inside the `div.Three`......

Comment: @ K K  Thank you! That is almost there. I've added a background style to it and it highlights it good, except if I select an adjacent radio button then the first checked one stays highlighted when it should instead turn off (when it's state becomes "ui-state-default") _- these do not multiselect_. Also if I select other radio buttons in a random order then the styling then becomes applied when the radio button is unchecked instead.....can an additional code be applied for other styling (or remove styling) when it is unchecked/inactive?

Comment: @K K  In addition to the issue above, I am also having trouble now with styling each radio button so they are joined together and of equal width. Its taking quite a lot of custom amendment styling on other elements. Do you now how I could style the above `span.Two` or `label.One` instead when using this method `.find(".Six").toggleClass("active")` ?

Comment: @JRNZ Just remove the applied styles by checking the conditions under which you want them to be removed

Comment: @K K - re your last comment, sorry I'm not really sure what you mean here.....I'm a fair bit of a novice :)